# Need regular expression for Spring controller GetMapping with path variable that excludes URLs with a certain prefix

Tags: regex, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to create a regular expression for my Spring controller method that matches all of the paths in my web application, except It also needs to exclude any traffic with the prefix **“/websock”** that comes in for my websocket server.  Here is the method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{path:[^\\.]*}")
public String redirect(@PathVariable(value="path") String path) {
    LOGGER.debug("In redirect path:" + path);
    return "forward:/";
}
```

I have tried a lot of examples from the web I have not been able to find one that does what I need.  My examples have either accepted all traffic (including the websocket prefix), or that have excluded some of the http traffic.

The first reg-ex was

```
"/{path:[^\\.]*}"
```

which matches URLs such “http://localhost:8080/abc”.   But, it was failing to match http://localhost:8080/abc/def.

My second attempt using

```
"/**/{path:[^\\.]*}"
```

corrected that issue but then matched everything including my websocket traffic.

I tried the following, which I saw from other questions, was supposed to exclude traffic starting with "/websock".   But instead it failed to match anything including the “abc” URLs above:

```
"/{path:[^\\.]*}", "/**/{path:^(?!websock).*}/{path:[^\\.]*}".
```

What am I doing wrong with my reg-ex?